Selecting the appropriate .NET MAUI version for a mobile app with map, camera, and file system features
I’ve been exploring .NET MAUI 8 and I’m planning to develop a mobile application that needs to integrate map functionality, utilize the camera, and access files on the device. I’m considering the different .NET MAUI application types (standard .NET MAUI, .NET MAUI Blazor, .NET MAUI FluentUI Blazor, etc.) and I’m unsure which one to choose for these specific requirements. Could someone provide insights on which version or type of .NET MAUI application would be most suitable? Are there any particular libraries or packages that are recommended for handling maps, camera access, and file management within a .NET MAUI app?
Thank you for your assistance.
I’ve tested various .NET MAUI 8 application types but it’s unclear which is best for map functions, camera, and file handling. I was expecting clear guidance, but the documentation hasn’t been enough to decide.

Please read [ask] before posting.  This is soliciting opinions, which is off topic

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
